# How to convert days to hours in pandas

Tags: pandas

Example:

```
coupon             expiration
Restaurant         1d
College            2d
Coffee House       2h
```

o/p:

```
coupon             expiration
Restaurant         24h
College            48h
Coffee House       2h
```

How to convert days to hours in pandas

Comment: You will have to use string manipulation with your own logic.  These are not time nor timeperiod values.  IE.  Extract number from string multiply by 24 then convert back to string and add 'h'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) on the `expiration` column and use a **regex** pattern to select those entries that have a day (**d**) suffix. You can also call a function for the `repl` parameter - which is where I chose to do the conversion to hours.

#### Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"coupon":['Restaurant','College','Coffee House'], "expiration":['1d','2d','2h']})

def replacement(m):
    x = int(m.group(0).split('d')[0]) * 24
    return f"{x}h"

df.expiration = df.expiration.str.replace(pat=r'^\d+d$', repl=replacement, regex=True)
print(df)
```

#### Output:

```
         coupon expiration
0    Restaurant        24h
1       College        48h
2  Coffee House         2h
```

#### Regex Pattern:

```
r'^\d+d$'
```

- `^` : start of string
- `\d+` : one or more digits [0-9]
- `d` : followed by the letter d
- `$` : end of string

#### Note:

If you would rather a **one-liner** using a lambda function instead:

```
df.expiration = df.expiration.str.replace(pat=r'^\d+d$', repl= lambda m:f"{int(m.group(0).split('d')[0]) * 24}h", regex=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.to_timedelta`, but the values in the expiration column must be valid timedelta strings:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard() # Your df here

tds = pd.to_timedelta(df["expiration"])
# 0   1 days 00:00:00
# 1   2 days 00:00:00
# 2   0 days 02:00:00
# Name: expiration, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

# I would recommend stopping here, but you can reformat this into a string of hours:
df["expiration"] = tds.dt.total_seconds().div(3600).apply("{:g}h".format)

#         coupon expiration
# 0   Restaurant        24h
# 1      College        48h
# 2  CoffeeHouse         2h
```

Answer (score 1):

A simply Apply can help here

```
def convert(x):
    if 'd' in x:
        return f"{int(x.replace('d',''))*24}h"
    return x   
df['expiration']= df['expiration'].apply(lambda x:convert(x))
df
Out[57]: 
         coupon expiration
0    Restaurant        24h
1       College        48h
2  Coffee House         2h
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

```
df['expiration'] = [str(eval(x)) + 'h' for x in
                    df['expiration'].str.replace('d', '*24').str.replace('h', '')]
```

Output:

```
         coupon expiration
0    Restaurant        24h
1       College        48h
2  Coffee House         2h
```